# OpenGL: glGetError() returns invalid enum after call to glewInit()

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I use GLEW and freeglut. For some reason, after a call to glewInit(), glGetError() returns error code 1280. Reinstalling the drivers didn't help. I tried to disable glewExperimental, it had no effect. Code worked before, but I am not aware of any changes I could possibly make.

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GLenum GlewInitResult, res;

    InitWindow(argc, argv);

    res = glGetError(); // res = 0

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();    

    res = glGetError(); // res = 1280

    glutMainLoop();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
    GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);

    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

    GLenum errorCheckValue = glGetError();

    if (WindowHandle < 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not create new rendering window.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
    glutTimerFunc(0, TimerFunction, 0);
    glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyboardFunction);
}
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: is GLEW returning an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the `glewExperimental` support, as that may be attempting to call something in OpenGL that isn't supported by your particular driver.  That actual error is `GL_INVALID_ENUM`​ which, unfortunately, can be raised from pretty much anywhere.

Also, what OpenGL driver are you using and in what environment? Some drivers may allow you to enable a debug log or the like.  Unfortunately, GLEW itself is not written in a way that makes it easy to add in generic `glGetError()` checks after every extension query or the like, but you might be able to narrow it down by adding it in at strategic locations.

Comment: I tried to disable glewExperimental, it had no effect. I use Windows 7 64bit, latest AMD drivers.

Comment: Whoops, I had error in my vertex shader. GL_INVALID_ENUM wasn't really the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error code given, 1280, corresponds with GL error 0x0500

GL_INVALID_ENUM​, 0x0500: Given when an enumeration parameter is not a legal enumeration for that function. This is given only for local problems; if the spec allows the enumeration in certain circumstances, and other parameters or state dictate those circumstances, then GL_INVALID_OPERATION​ is the result instead.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes

Apparently one of the enums you are passing into OpenGL is bad. I've never used GLUT so I have no idea what the possible enum error could be.